# Python programing not going to else after break?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, break, code-formatting

In my program, if there no data found at page for eg.10, then for the rest of the pages, 11 to 50, it is not going into the  else statement (which should happen). I am new to python and need help to sort this problem in the code written below:

```
import concurrent
import functools
import concurrent.futures
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
import csv

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

def download_page(session, page_no):
    url = 'https://bidplus.gem.gov.in/bidlists?d=1&page_no=' + str(page_no)
    print('URL created: ' + url)
    resp = session.get(url, verify=False)
    return resp.text


def scrap_bid_data():
    NUMBER_THREADS =5 # number of concurrent download requests
    with open('GEMconcurrent_1004.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
        f = csv.writer(out_file)
        f.writerow(['Bidnumber', 'Items', 'Quantity', 'Department', 'Enddate','pageNumber'])
        with requests.Session() as session:
            page_downloader = functools.partial(download_page, session)
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUMBER_THREADS) as executor:
                pages = executor.map(page_downloader, range(35, 36 ))
                page_no = 0
                for page in pages:
                    page_no += 1
                    soup_data = bs(page, 'lxml')
                    extracted_data = soup_data.find('div', {'id': 'pagi_content'})
                    if extracted_data is None or len(extracted_data) == 0:
                        print('No data at page number', page_no)
                        print(page)
                        break
                    else:
                        for idx in range(len(extracted_data)):
                            if (idx % 2 == 1):
                                bid_data = extracted_data.contents[idx].text.strip().split('\n')
                                if (len(bid_data)>1):
                                    print(page_no)
                                    if (len(bid_data[8]) > 1):

                                                            bidno = bid_data[0].split(":")[-1]
                                                            items = bid_data[8].split(":")[-1]
                                                            qnty = int(bid_data[9].split(':')[1].strip())
                                                            dept = (bid_data[10] + bid_data[15].strip()).split(":")[-1]
                                                            edate = bid_data[20].split("End Date:")[-1]
                                                            f.writerow([bidno, items, qnty, dept, edate,page_no])
scrap_bid_data()
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve] that we can copy&paste and it just runs.

Comment: When the `if` succeeds the program encounters a `break`, so it exits the loop. Just remove that

Comment: With `break` you break the `for` loop (`for page in pages:`). Why do you expect the program to continue after the `else` statement?

Comment: @MikeScotty okay, I gotta know - how do you do inline links with custom titles? If you could point me in the right direction please

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links

Answer (score 0):

Break is used when you want to move out of the condition (loop containing it).

A more detailed explanation here https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue.

I do not think you need to use break here.

Comment: While true, the OP is trying to use a for-else loop as described here:
https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html

Answer (score 0):

You have the code formatted in the following way:

```
for p in pages:
   do stuff
   if condition:
      do stuff
      break
   else:
```

but if you want to run the `else` clause on breaks, you need to format it to be on the same level as the `for loop`:

```
for p in pages:
    do stuff
    if condition:
        do stuff
        break
else:
   #i got here because of the break statement
```

Comment: You have it backwards. The `else` clause is run if the iterator is exhausted; it's skipped if the loop is exited by `break`.